# How to put growl notification using applescript?

Tags: macos, growl, growlnotify

I am using a script which updates my working copy of SVN.

I've installed Growl. I want to put Growl notifications once my script finishes updating my working copy of SVN.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit of searching on Google and in Growl's site could have solved your problem.

[Click here](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php) to know about it.

Or directly copy paste this code in your apple script editor and see how it works.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set isRunning to (count of (every process whose bundle identifier is "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp")) > 0
end tell

if isRunning then
    tell application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp"
        -- Make a list of all the notification types 
        -- that this script will ever send:
        set the allNotificationsList to ¬
            {"Test Notification", "Another Test Notification"}

        -- Make a list of the notifications 
        -- that will be enabled by default.      
        -- Those not enabled by default can be enabled later 
        -- in the 'Applications' tab of the Growl preferences.
        set the enabledNotificationsList to ¬
            {"Test Notification"}

        -- Register our script with growl.
        -- You can optionally (as here) set a default icon 
        -- for this script's notifications.
        register as application ¬
            "Growl AppleScript Sample" all notifications allNotificationsList ¬
            default notifications enabledNotificationsList ¬
            icon of application "Script Editor"

        --       Send a Notification...
        notify with name ¬
            "Test Notification" title ¬
            "Test Notification" description ¬
            "This is a test AppleScript notification." application name "Growl AppleScript Sample"

        notify with name ¬
            "Another Test Notification" title ¬
            "Another Test Notification :) " description ¬
            "Alas — you won't see me until you enable me..." application name "Growl AppleScript Sample"

    end tell
end if
```

I hope this should solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer using GrowlNotify (http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify) in scripts. It's an easier and more direct way of Growling via AppleScript.

Comment: I have tried GrowlNotify but I also have Bark installed and Growl doesn't seem to display GrowlNotify messages.